# setting classpath for java classes(jar file) in XUL, to access via javascript

Tags: java, javascript, classpath, xul

I am implementing firefox extension using XUL. I have set of java classes that is zipped as jar which needs to be accessed through javascript. 
   If I copy my jar into jre's lib/ext then javascript will be able to invoke my java classes. If I remove from ext and package this jar in xpi, Javascript is unable to find the classpath for my jar file. Please let me know how to set the classpath for my java classes(jar file) in XUL environment at the earliest.

Comment: javascript/XUL invoking java ? interesting... any ref ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at this extension

[XQuery USE ME 1.4.7](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5515)

and the following articles

[Calling java from XUL applications](http://stanislavvitvitskiy.blogspot.com/2009/04/calling-java-from-xul-applications.html)

[Java in Firefox Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Java_in_Firefox_Extensions)

Comment: Thanks, Is there any easy way to set the classpath such that javascript can find it.- Anand.